# What is the meaning of "use strict";globalThis.__codeBoxId = "gc8oqei2f4"; in js?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's code, what does the meaning of the words after "use strict" ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
"use strict";globalThis.__codeBoxId = "gc8oqei2f4";

let admin, name; // can declare two variables at once

name = "John";

admin = name;

alert( admin ); // "John"
</script>
```

Comment: "use strict" and the `globalThis` code are two separate instructions. Normally you'd write the stuff after the semicolon on a new line for readability. The second part just assigns a new property to `globalThis`

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, The global globalThis property contains the global this value, which is akin to the global object.

Why you should use it?

Historically, accessing the global object has required different syntax in different JavaScript environments. On the web you can use window, self, or frames - but in Web Workers only self will work. In Node.js none of these work, and you must instead use global.

The globalThis property provides a standard way of accessing the global 'this' value (and hence the global object itself) across environments. Unlike similar properties such as window and self, it's guaranteed to work in window and non-window contexts. In this way, you can access the global object in a consistent manner without having to know which environment the code is being run in. To help you remember the name, just remember that in global scope the this value is globalThis.

When should be use it?

When we need to create global object independent of cross-platform.

For more details, you should check :

1. [First](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/why-should-you-start-using-globalthis-in-javascript-fe811151a8b)
2. [Dev Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)

Comment: I don't think OP was asking about the "use strict" part itself. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66455293/what-is-use-strictglobalthis-codeboxid-gc8oqei2f4-in-js#comment117483763_66455293).